# Why is the wrong php.ini being used?

Tags: php, apache

I've got WordPress installed on an add-on domain (**shared hosting** environment), with a theme that uses `ini_get('allow_url_fopen')` to determine how to reference post images. `ini_get('allow_url_fopen')` is returning a value different than what is in my custom php.ini file, which is located in the WP installation directory.

If I run phpinfo() from a test file in the WP directory, I see that PHP is has these settings:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /usr/lib
Loaded Configuration File   /home/ACCOUNT/public_html/ADD-ON DIRECTORY/php.ini
```

If, however, I run phpinfo() from /home/ACCOUNT/public_html/ADD-ON DIRECTORY/wp-content, a different configuration file is used:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /usr/lib
Loaded Configuration File   /usr/local/lib/php.ini
```

Why is the wrong configuration file being loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, my host is using suPHP. And with suPHP (and, I presume, phpSuExec), subdirectories do not inherit the configuration from php.ini files. (They will use the default php.ini.)

http://www.geeksengine.com/article/php-include-path.html

Two ways around this:

- Place a custom php.ini file in each directory where scripts are loaded from
- Use a `suPHP_ConfigPath /home/username/public_html/` directive in .htaccess to point to the directory containing your custom php.ini and have it affect all subdirectories that don't already contain a php.ini

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem related to your hosting company, not to php in particular. If you are using a specific system that you build yourself, you'll need to look at which apache extension is used to run php files.

For example, on my system i built for work, i use SUPHP as a script engine. This allows me to configure where to look for a specific PHP.ini file.

Good luck

Comment: That's what I figured. However, I often find hosting support to be less informed than I. Is there something specific I can ask them about?

Comment: And to add more intrigue to my dilemma, I've found that if I copy my custom php.ini file to the lower directory, PHP will load it. Boggling why the file in the parent directory isn't being used. And, so far, my host has been unhelpful.